# Can finite state machines with conditional transitions be expressed as Markov chains?

Tags: uml, state, fsm, chain, markov

I'd be curious to know whether finite state machines that have conditional transitions can be expressed as Markov chains? If they can't, what would be a good counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

A Markov Chain is a "recording" of a state machine where you have probablities between state changes. A UML state machine does not directly have these probablities. State transitions only have guards (and some other attributes). So in order to create a Markov Chain you need a profile which defines state transitions that also offer probabilities. Maybe (depends on your use case) you can simply use the guards to express these probabilities.